# Does deflecting missiles work against multiple missiles at once?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

I am playing a monk and am reading the rules. In regards to **Deflect Missiles**, are you able to deflect one or many?

I would assume it is one because the rules say "you can use your reaction to deflect or catch the missile", and I believe you can only have one reaction per round.

But at the very start of the monk description in the Player's Handbook it says "Her fists a blur as they deflect an incoming hail of arrows", which would imply that you can deflect as many as would hit you.

Comment: The following question is similar and might be of interest to you too: [How many times can a monk use Deflect Missile in a round?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59383/how-many-times-can-a-monk-use-deflect-missile-in-a-round).

Answer (score 27):

### Just one missile per round

(despite the name)

[Deflect Missiles](http://www.5esrd.com/classes/monk/#Deflect_Missiles) says:
*"you can use your **reaction** to deflect or catch **the** missile when you are hit by **a** ranged weapon attack."* (the rest of the description similarly refers to just one attack). And since you only get one reaction per round, you can only deflect one attack.