# If a dagger thrown at a monk splits into multiple daggers mid-air, each with their own attack and damage rolls, can Deflect Missiles deflect them all?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, skills, monk, reactions

Situation:

A dagger is thrown at a monk. On that attack, the dagger multiplies into 2 or 3 daggers in mid-air, each dagger with its own rolls for attack and damage. The daggers move one after another such as a line like:

— — —

As a reaction to that one Attack action, can a monk use [Deflect Missiles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#DeflectMissiles-231) to deflect all of those projectiles, since all of them were thrown on a single Attack action and will be arriving simultaneously?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92657/discussion-on-question-by-majinmonkey-if-a-dagger-thrown-at-a-monk-splits-into-m).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, the monk cannot deflect them all.  The magic dagger is making three separate attacks.

Each attack roll is a separate attack.  The dagger is essentially performing the same mechanic as the extra attack class feature for the player.  Deflect missiles can only handle a single missile from a single attack.

> Starting at 3rd level, you can use your reaction to deflect or catch **the** missile when you are hit by **a ranged weapon attack**. When you do so, the damage you take from the attack is reduced by 1d10 + your Dexterity modifier + your monk level.

The question is a magical item powered re-hash of: [Does deflecting missiles work against multiple missiles at once?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97344/does-deflecting-missiles-work-against-multiple-missiles-at-once)

Comment: Might also be worth bolding "a ranged weapon attack" - the reaction is used on one such attack, not multiple.

Comment: @V2Blast thanks.  That also jogs my memory about thrown weapons not being ranged weapon attacks.

Comment: Actually, thrown weapons are ranged weapon attacks. They're just (mostly) made with melee weapons. From [weapon properties](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties): "Thrown. If a weapon has the thrown property, **you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack**. If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon." Basically, almost every attack is either a melee or ranged attack, and either a weapon or spell attack. They are ranged weapon attacks.

Comment: @V2Blast I thought the ruling was daggers, spears, and javelins were not ranged weapons.

Comment: They aren't ranged weapons; they're melee weapons used for ranged weapon attacks.

Comment: @V2Blast answers like [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87566/38434) and the sage advice "No, the Archery feature benefits
ranged weapons. A melee weapon, such as a dagger or
handaxe, is still a melee weapon when you make a ranged
attack with it." Is attack with ranged weapon a "ranged weapon attack" and a thrown dagger a "ranged attack" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92661/discussion-between-gcl-and-v2blast).